# Check number of elements given to std::array compile time

Tags: c++, static-assert, stdarray

I have a performance critical code where I query N indices. How can I check compile-time with a `static_assert` whether exactly N indices are given, without sacrificing performance?

```
#include <array>

template<int N>
void test(const std::array<int, N>& indices)
{
    // static_assert:  has three elements.
    return;
}

int main()
{
    test<3>({1, 2, 3}); // OK
    test<3>({1, 2});    // Needs to crash, because 2 < 3

    test<2>({1, 2, 3}); // Crashes, because 3 > 2
    test<2>({1, 2});    // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's ugly, but it kind of works: https://godbolt.org/z/1S11GE . The overload is ambiguous for the second case

Comment: Why use a std::array if you always want 3 items and you don't want a partial initializer?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Why not? That's exactly what std::array gives.

Comment: @Justin yes but in his case he doesn't want a partial initializer

Comment: Use variadic templates instead

Comment: Another alternative: https://godbolt.org/z/HhRGwe

Comment: @Justin. My real usecase is more complex. I have refined the question to show my problem.

Comment: Why not change `test()` so it accepts three arguments of type `int`?   That means the calling syntax doesn't need the `{}` for the initialiser  (i.e. `test(1,2,3)` rather than `test({1,2,3})`) and a compilation error if you get the number of values wrong.  You can also use a variadic template if needed.

Comment: @ArneJ How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I check compile-time with a static_assert whether three indices are given

You can't.  They array is of size 3 so it will always have 3 elements.  When you do something like

```
test({1, 2});
```

The array initializes the first two elements with `1` and `2` and then zero-initializes the last element.  This is how aggregate initialization works and you can't change it.

What you need to do is either add overloads for arrays of size 1 and 2 and delete them, or you could just change the function to have 3 parameters and then it must be called with 3 values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<int N, typename ...Args>
void test(Args... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N);
    std::array<int, N> arr{ args... };
    for (auto&& elm : arr) {
        std::cout << elm << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    test<3>(1, 2, 3); // OK
    //test<3>(1, 2);    // Crashes

    //test<2>( 1, 2, 3 ); // Crashes
    test<2>(1, 2);    // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Uses variadic templates instead.

Answer (score 2):

A bit ugly, but should work - a wrapper for `std::array`:

```
class MyArray 
{
public:
    MyArray(int x, int y, int z): _array{x, y, z} 
    {};
private:
    std::array<int, 3> _array;
};

void test(const MyArray&) {
    //no need to check values here
}
```

You won't be able to create an object of this wrapper class with less than 3 arguments. [See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tJXCQ39AuVEP1Qnr).

Of course, it won't work for general case you mentioned, but it should make it possible to differentiate certain classes.

Comment: You can make this work for the general case by having an `N` parameter like `std::array`, and a variadic constructor which tests that the number of parameters is `N`.

Comment: @Justin I don't understand those well enough to use them correctly, but fortunately anyone can provide another answer here ;)